# What is the best way to monitor compaction strategy performance over time for DSE clusters?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

As stated in the title, I'm wondering what the best way to monitor compaction strategy performance is on my DSE cluster over time, as it (the database) grows.  The current strategy in use is leveledCompaction.

Any information, input, guides, etc. you can recommend for monitoring strategy are welcome.

Comment: check here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dseplanning/docs/bestPractices.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several free tools you can use to monitor [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) clusters. The relevant metrics to monitor include active compactions, pending compactions, and blocked compactions.

### OpsCenter

[DSE OpsCenter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/about_c.html) is a visual monitoring tool that collects metrics about your cluster and allows you to view the performance metrics over time.

Have a look at the [compaction thread pool metrics](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/online_help/TPCmetrics.html) for details.

### Metrics Collector

The [DSE Metrics Collector](https://docs.datastax.com/en/monitoring/doc/monitoring/opsUseMetricsCollector.html) is built on [`collectd`](https://collectd.org/) and aggregates metric data from your cluster that can be exported to existing monitoring systems including [Prometheus](https://docs.datastax.com/en/monitoring/doc/monitoring/metricsCollector/mcExportMetricsManually.html#mcExportMetricsManually). There are [pre-configured Grafana dashboards](https://github.com/datastax/dse-metric-reporter-dashboards/tree/master/grafana/dashboards) you can use out-of-the-box.

Have a look at the [Compaction](https://docs.datastax.com/en/monitoring/doc/monitoring/opsCompactionMetrics.html) and [Thread pool statistics](https://docs.datastax.com/en/monitoring/doc/monitoring/opsThreadPoolStats.html) for available metrics. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!